# Mongo 4.0 replaceOne doesn't support field with dollar sign

Tags: mongodb

As the doc [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/core/document/#field-names) said,

> Top-level field names cannot start with the dollar sign ($) character.
>
> Otherwise, starting in MongoDB 3.6, the server permits storage of field names that contain
> dots (i.e. .) and dollar signs (i.e. $).

However, it only works when I insert a new doc. It'll fail when I call `replaceOne` with the updated doc like below in the mongo shell:

```
db.somecollection.insertOne({_id:"1", StepLog: {$test:1}})
doc = db.somecollection.findOne({_id:"1"})
doc.StepLog.$test=2
db.somecollection.replaceOne({_id:"1"}, doc)
```

Error:

> 022-01-11T04:59:19.824+0000 E QUERY    [js] WriteError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$test' in 'StepLog.$test' is not valid for storage. :
> WriteError({
> "index" : 0,
> "code" : 52,
> "errmsg" : "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$test' in 'StepLog.$test' is not valid for storage.",
> "op" : {
> "q" : {
> "_id" : "1"
> },
> "u" : {
> "_id" : "1",
> "StepLog" : {
> "$test" : 2
> }
> },
> "multi" : false,
> "upsert" : false
> }
> })

My question is how can I use replaceOne for non top level field with the dollar sign.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you note the highlighted text in the "important" box immediately following that line in the docs?

Comment: I see it, but don't get how it is related to my question. it's not recommended but it should work, right?

Comment: It clearly states: *The MongoDB Query Language cannot always meaningfully express queries* It also says  the use of $ and . in field names is not recommended. If you really insist to run voluntarily intro problems, then upgrade your MongoDB to version 5 which [improved support $ and . in field names](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/dot-dollar-considerations/#std-label-crud-concepts-dot-dollar-considerations) Personally I would prefer if MongoDB generally would prohibit the use of  $ and . in field names. But once if it possible (even by mistake) then it is difficult to revert.